# C# automatic casting when calling overloaded function

Tags: c#, casting, operator-overloading

Let's imagine that I have the following overloaded function:

```
void DoSomething(int x) { ... }
void DoSomething(float x) { ... }
void DoSomething(decimal x) { ... }
```

In the following method, I need to call the correct overload. This is how a simple implementation would look like:

```
void HaveToDoSomething(object data)
{
    if (data is int) DoSomething((int)data);
    else if (data is float) DoSomething((float)data);
    else if (data is decimal) DoSomething((decimal)data);
}
```

This is tedious when there are ~20 types to check. Is there a better way of doing all this casting automatically?

Something I forgot to mention: `DoSomething` wouldn't work with generics, as each type needs to be handled differently, and I only know the type at runtime.

Comment: Make `DoSomething` generic

Comment: Can you change the `DoSomething` implementation?

Comment: From where do you get the `data`? The source of it doesn't provide any information about the type of it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I don't think generics would work in my case, each type needs to be handled differently. For example, if you need to serialize the data to a particular format, each type needs to be handled differently.

Comment: Methods are bound at compile-time normally.  If you want to bind methods based on the run-time type you'll have to use reflection or `dynamic`.

Comment: @mjwills Yes, dynamic is the approach that I think I saw once, but forgot about it. The 'reflection' approach is more useful since it can also be applied in Java. I don't know which answer to choose, since there can only be one, and both are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Reflection` but it can have a performance impact:

```
public class Example
{
    void DoSomething(int i)
    {

    }

    void DoSomething(float i)
    {

    }
}

public static class ExampleExtensions
{
    public static void DoSomethingGeneric(this Example example, object objectParam)
    {
        var t = objectParam.GetType();
        var methods = typeof(example).GetMethods().Where(_ => _.Name == "DoSomething");
        var methodInfo = methods.Single(_ => _.GetParameters().First().ParameterType == t);
        methodInfo.Invoke(example, new[] { objectParam });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach would be to use `dynamic`:

```
void HaveToDoSomething(dynamic data)
{
    DoSomething(data);
}
```

Comment: Note that while this approach looks pretty neat, it might lead to a performance loss when used e.g. in a tight loop.

Comment: That is correct @dymanoid - `dynamic` can have performance impacts. Whether it is an issue in this scenario is hard to say.

Comment: Since any solution other than generics is going to involve reflection anyway, this seems like a good approach.

Comment: @MatthewWatson The OP's (working) code doesn't involve reflection.

Comment: @Servy Not in the context of the OP's question: "Is there a better way of doing all this casting automatically?" - As far as I know any solution involving "casting automatically" is going to involve reflection (other than solutions involving using special tools to generate code at compile time...)

Comment: @MatthewWatson The OP asked for a better way, the solution provides a worse way.  If you don't know of any solution that's better, then don't answer, rather than posting an answer that's worse.  If you can demonstrate that there *isn't* a better way, then explaining that there is no answer *would* be an answer.

Comment: @Servy The issue is that 'better' has a semantically broad range in English. I suspect your interpretation of 'better' may not be aligned with that of the OP. The OP's post states `This is tedious when there are ~20 types to check.` which strongly implies (by the context) that 'better' for him/her at least _partly_ means reducing the repetitive code. This solution assists with that. _I appreciate that it may not meet your requirements or definition of 'better', but ultimately that was not my aim._

Comment: @mjwills I agree that the question is in fact highly opinion based in what it is asking, and it does not adequately explain what it is asking for.  That doesn't make the problems go away, it makes them worse.

Comment: It makes the problems worse for your understanding of the problem @Servy. But for the OP's problem (which is 'tediousness of code' not 'performance') then I would argue it **does** make the problem go away. _Context is important - and when answering a question I need to provide an answer in the context of what the OP is asking for, not what I **think** they should be asking for._

Comment: @mjwills It makes what you guess is the OP's problem go away *while introducing other major problems that didn't exist before*.  And of course saying that you shouldn't be acting based on what you *think* the question is, while also explaining what you're *assuming* the OP's question is, is rather hypocritical.

Comment: Given the OP stated both answers were helpful, I think it is safe to say that my reading of the question was accurate.